# How to add elements to a HStack Using ForEach SwiftUi

Tags: variables, swiftui, progress-bar, hstack, swiftui-foreach

Im fairly new to Swift and I'm trying to produce a HStack (that will be used in a progress bar) of element and to be able to add elements with a button.

Im not sure if I should use a variable in the `ForEach(1..<Variable)` section or use another method.

Here is the code I have so far but it did not work.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fill : CGFloat = 0
    @State var NumberOfCircles : Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing:100) {
            ForEach(0..<NumberOfCircles){ _ in
                MyShape()
            }

            Button(action: {NumberOfCircles = 5}, label: {
                Text("Button")  
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with this code? Saying "it did not work" doesn't tell us the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` in SwiftUI needs a constant range to loop over. However,
as the error suggests, if you conform to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id` it is happy. So try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fill: CGFloat = 0
    @State var NumberOfCircles: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(0..<NumberOfCircles, id: \.self){ _ in // <-- here
                MyShape()
            }
            Button(action: {NumberOfCircles = 5}){
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your problem, but I tested this code and it works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var numberOfCircles = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<numberOfCircles, id:\.self) { _ in
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                }
            }
            Button { numberOfCircles = 5 } label: {
            Text("Add Circles")
        }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, naming convention for variables in Swift is camelCase. That means that declaring a variable you should name it `numberOfCircles` , not `NumberOfCircles` . The first uppercase letter is reserved for naming Classes, Structs and Protocols.